# calling a function from a different context using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to call a function/Method in javscript using OOP style but from a different context.

for example:

```
var SomeClass = function(){
    this.init = function(){
        var something = "An Interesting Variable";
        this.foo(something); //this works fine
    },
    this.foo = function(bar){
        alert(bar);
    }
    this.foo2 = function(){
        this.foo(something); // this deos not work/ something is not defined
    }

};

var newClass = new SomeClass();
newClass.init();
newClass.foo2();
```

so basically i want to call `this.foo()` function within the `this.foo2()` context, but acting as the `this.init()`, im not sure this makes sense, but im new to OOP in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context is right, but you're trying to access a variable that isn't defined in that scope. The variable `something`, declared with `var` within `init` will only live inside that function.

You need to make it a member of `SomeClass`:

```
this.init = function() {
   this.something = 'An interesting variable';
   this.foo(this.something);
},

this.foo2 = function() {
   this.foo(this.something);
}
```